# How to solve $ \begin{cases} \cos (z_1 +iz_2) = i\\ |z_1|=|z_2| \end{cases} $?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

How to solve
$ \begin{cases}
 \cos (z_1 +iz_2) = i\\
|z_1|=|z_2|
\end{cases}
$?

where $z_1, z_2$ are complex variables

Rectangular form is convenient for the first equation, and polar form is suitable for the second one! What to do?

Comment: Is that a system of complex variables, Mahdi?

Comment: @BabakS. Yes it is. Happy eating!

Comment: Have you tried using the identity: $\cos(u+v) = \cos(u)\cos(v)-\sin(u)\sin(v)$ ?

Comment: @kvmu Then we will have $\cos z_1 \cos iz_2 - \sin z_1\sin iz_2 = i$. Now, rectangular or polar form is better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve $\cos(w) = i$, then let $z_1 = z_2 = w/(1+i)$.  Of course this is only one solution.  Do you want *all* solutions?

Comment: Thank you! But how many answers it would have? would you mind giving me some others too?

Comment: There are countably many solutions to $\cos w = i$.  So then the question is, for given $w$, what is the set $\{(z_1,z_2):z_1+iz_2 = w, |z_1| = |z_2|\}$ ?

Comment: obviously they are two lines in two 2D space each for real and imaginary components

Comment: So, in total your set consists of countably many real lines in $\mathbb C^2$.